# use OR in hdfstore select pandas

Tags: python, pandas, select, hdfstore

I know how to use AND type of query in pandas HDFStore.select, but how can I use OR?

for example, I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(100),
                'B': randn(100),
                'C': randn(100).cumsum()},
                index=pd.bdate_range(end=pd.Timestamp('20131031 23:59:00'), periods=100))
df1.to_hdf('testHDF.h5', 'testVar1', format='table', data_columns=True, append=True)
```

Then I can use the following to partially load from this dataset

```
store = pd.HDFStore('testHDF.h5')
store.select('testVar1', [pd.Term('index', '>=', pd.Timestamp('20131017')), 'A > 0'])
```

or

```
store.select('tableVar2', where=('A > 0', 'B > 0', 'index >= 20131017'))
```

Apparently, it is using AND to combine all the criteria I provided, such as ('A > 0' AND 'B > 0' AND 'index >= 20131017')

My question is, how can I use OR, such as the returned result is ('A > 0' OR 'B > 0')?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in 0.12, you have to concat the result of selecting multiple criteria (keeping in mind that you may generate duplicates)

```
In [9]: pd.concat([store.select('testVar1', where=('A > 0', 'index >= 20131017')),
                   store.select('testVar1', where=('B > 0', 'index >= 20131017'))]).drop_duplicates().sort_index()
Out[9]: 
                   A         B          C
2013-10-17  0.156248  0.085911  10.238636
2013-10-22 -0.125369  0.335910  10.865678
2013-10-23 -2.531444  0.690332  12.335883
2013-10-24 -0.266777  0.501257  13.529781
2013-10-25  0.815413 -0.629418  14.690554
2013-10-28  0.383213 -0.587026  13.589094
2013-10-31  1.897674  0.361764  14.595062

[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

In 0.13/master (0.13rc1 is out!), you can just do a very natural query

```
In [10]: store.select('testVar1', where='(A > 0 | B > 0) & index >= 20131017')
Out[10]: 
                   A         B          C
2013-10-17  0.156248  0.085911  10.238636
2013-10-22 -0.125369  0.335910  10.865678
2013-10-23 -2.531444  0.690332  12.335883
2013-10-24 -0.266777  0.501257  13.529781
2013-10-25  0.815413 -0.629418  14.690554
2013-10-28  0.383213 -0.587026  13.589094
2013-10-31  1.897674  0.361764  14.595062

[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I need to update my pandas package, or load the DataFrame first, and then do the subsetting

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: Not the newest, I got 0.12.0, comes with anaconda distribution

Comment: I don't know how to update pandas to 0.13.0 since I already have 0.12.0
I will try to update and play with it once 0.13.0 becomes official.
Thanks.

Comment: 0.13rc1 is out, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-build/dev/ or use git to clone if on linux